# How to calculate the maximal temperature of a transistor

Tags: temperature, pmos

let's assume I have this transistor (IRFR640):
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFR6215-DS-v01_02-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563595592114

$$R_{DS(ON)} =0,295 \Omega $$
$$V_{max} = -150V$$
$$I_{max} =-13A $$
$$I_{load)} =260mA $$
$$T_{a} =50°C \Omega $$
$$R_{\theta ja} =50°C/W$$
We apply on the drain 100V (\$V_d = 100V\$)

What is the good calculation?

1) $$T_{PMOS} =T_a + R_{\theta ja}*R_{DS(ON)}*I_{load}^2 $$
So
$$T_{PMOS} =50 + 110*0,295*(260*10^{-3})^2 = 52,2°C $$

2)$$T_{PMOS} =T_a + R_{\theta ja}*V_{d}*I_{load} = 894°C $$

What is the good answer? And why?
I use same power dissipation
Tthanks

Comment: When Vd = 100 V and Rdson = 0.295 ohm then 338A will flow, that is **unrealistic**, that would exceed Id_max and P_max so calculation 2 is **unrealistic**.

Comment: Equation 2 is more correct, but it is not Vd. It is Vds, the voltage from drain to source of the transistor. I guess that would be 100V - Vload, assuming there is some load connected between 100V and drain of transistor. Really, to get a good answer, you should draw a circuit schematic.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Doesn't mean that my transistor will be breakdown? I just cangeV*I to R*I^2, why results are so differents?

Comment: @mkeith Yes, we assume the load is connected there is some load connected between 100V and drain of transistor.
The schematic is here: https://i.imgur.com/Ys6loDT.png

Comment: Use the built-in schematic editor to draw your schematic, don't make us click through a link.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find the "built-in schematic" editor

Comment: What is your load?  And why P-Channel MOSFET?

Comment: My load is another board, that needs 260mA. I choose it, because the maximal current is 13A, and the maximal voltage is 150V. So, why can't I send 260mA with 100V?

Comment: OK, so you want to switch ON/OFF the 100V supply rail that needs 260mA max?

Comment: Yes, I want to switch ON/OFF the 100V supply rail that needs 260mA max, and I want to know if my transistor can handle that.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumptions must be invalid. It is **not possible** that \$V_{DS} = 100\mathrm{V}\$, \$I_{DS}=260\mathrm{mA}\$, and \$R_{DS}=0.295\Omega\$. Before you can calculate the transistor's die temperature you must analyze the circuit and determine the actual operating conditions.

Comment: I didn't understand. Because the transistor can handle these voltages and current. So why is there something wrong?

Comment: @Tack Ohms law, if you have 100 V and 0.295 ohms you have more than 260 mA.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand. 100V with 0,295 ohms => 344A. And that's more than what the transistor could give (13A).

Comment: I think I found the answer
We assume that:
$$I_d = 260mA$$
$$V_S = Vd - R_{DS(ON)}*I_d = 100-0,295*260*0,001 = 99,9233V$$
And so
$$V_{DS} = V_d-Vs = 0,0767$$
$$T_{PMOS} =T_a + R_{\theta ja}*V_{d}*I_{load} $$
So
T_{PMOS} =50 + 0,295*260*10^{-3} = 52,19°C
Same results. :)

Comment: I can't edit my post, sorry.
$$T_{PMOS} =T_a + R_{\theta ja}*V_{ds}*I_{load}$$
$$T_{PMOS} =50 + 0,295*260*10^{-3}*0,0767 = 52,19°C$$ 
Expected: 52,2°C
Thank you all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit should look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG3Tyc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And the static power dissipation

\$P = 0.56\Omega \cdot 260mA \cdot 260mA \approx 38mW  \$

Hence the static power dissipation is not a problem (if the ON/OFF period is long <1KHz).

Comment: Thank you very much for your circuit. I just have questions, why do we need R1? And what is the 0,56 ohms?

Comment: R1 is needed to pull-up the P-MOS gate to 100V rail and to discharge P-MOS Cgs capacitance to turn OFF the P_MOS when Q2 is OFF. And 0.56ohms is a Rds_max.

Comment: And so why R2? Did you added Q2 because of Vghth of Q1?

Comment: In this case, I add R2 because your MOSFET Vgs_max is equal to +/-20V. Hence R2 resistor limits the Vgs value to 10V. R2 also limits the Cgs charging current when P-MOS turn-ON. And Q2 is needed to control ON/OFF of a P-MOS from a 3.3V signal referenced to ground. Because to turn-OFF the P-MOS, the Voltage at the gate should be equal to about 96V, and 3.3V cannot do this. And to fully turn it ON about 90 volts is needed( but cannot be lower than 80V).

Comment: Basically R2 is needed to limit the Zener diode (D1) current when Q2 turns on. Without R2, the Zener current could be very high.